# Arduino Local Network DHCP Failed

Tags: networking, arduino-uno, ethernet, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

Hi there,

I will search and tried lots of solution for our problem but none of works. This will be a long post so be ready.

Our System:

We have an **arduino uno r3 clone** and **ethernet shield wiznet w5100**,
This Arduino  makes a **http post request** to a **windows web service.**
According to response arduino will make something that is not revelant to question.

So in our test environment, we will install a windows webservice to our windows machine and plug this machine to our local network.  Then plug arduino to our local network too. than with our server ip ,arduino made an dhcp request get ip from our modem-router and can call webservices from our server.

From now on everything works fine.

Here is some sample code from our arduino.(I only use this extra library for arduino:["RestClient.h"](https://github.com/csquared/arduino-restclient)

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "RestClient.h"
RestClient client = RestClient("192.168.100.17",51200);
String response;
String PostData;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  byte mac[] = { 0x04, 0xD6, 0x2E, 0x81, 0x01, 0xB0 };

  if ( Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
     Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  }
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void postDataToServer(long rfidnumber,int rfidsource){
  String postedRFIDNumber=String(rfidnumber);
  postedRFIDNumber="000"+postedRFIDNumber;
  response = "";
  PostData="RFID="+postedRFIDNumber+"&SOURCE="+rfidsource;
  const char * myPost = PostData.c_str();
  int statusCode = 
 client.post("/sqlpublish/TTSWebService.asmx/INSERT_INDEXRFID",myPost,&response);
}
```

We need to install our system to a company. This Company has its own local network. they have very restricted local network. You can connect their network but can not go to the "www" without their permissions. But that is not problem. We will use only local connection for our web services because we will also use an windows server which will inside local network.

This is a picture of their network system schema:
[image: Normal Network Configuration]
In this picture switches is missing but you can simply guess they uses lots of swtiches .Because company is very wide and have lots of device.

So if I connect any device to their local network , this device first call dhcp protocals get ip from **Windows DHCP Server** and then can communicate in the local network with other devices. But can not get through the internet modem because of the firewall in the router.

Then We will setup our system like this:

[image: our needed setup arduino]

In this setup switch models are : "AVAYA".

**VSP7000 XLS
ERS4826 GTS-PWR+
ERS3549 GTS-PWR+**

Firewall is: Watchguard Firebox M300

When we setup the system something weird is going on. First of all when I connect my PC(My Device) to local network I can call webservices in the windows server. But Arduino cannot get IP from DHCP Server, and naturaly cannot connect to web services. So we think that "ok we can give IP static". Than we will give IP to our Arduino manually. After that weird things started to begin. When Arduino try to conenct our Windows webservices it only get response some times. Roughly 1 of 20 has got response from server anything else get time out connection.And also succeded response time also too long.

If we ping our static arduino IP From another Device(For example Device_1), It get response sometimes again. (Same Amount)

So then we try to narrow down our problem.

First Of All We Change the setup like this for once to make sure problem in local network.

[image: changed version]

And Normaly all systems works perfectly. So our  Modem's DHCP server  make it works perfectly.(Also in this setup If I give Ip static it worked too).

So there is these possibilties for connection error.

1-Firewall
2-Switch problem
3-Arduino Clon Problem.

**1-Firewall**

When We talked about the problem with system admin, He told ust every local network connection and port is open in the firewall. He is probably right because any pc connect to local network can call the web sevice.

**2-Switch problem**

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736791/arduino-dhcp-not-working), talks about it as a solution it says use static ip, bu in our case it did not solve the problem.

[In this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039895/arduino-local-dns-problems) jdr5ca answer make sense but ı hve no idea how can test the problem or solve the problem

[In this Question answer tried but not working.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606816/arduino-ethernet-and-dhcp-cannot-communicate-out-to-the-internet)

Lastly [this post](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/cant-connect-to-my-arduino-via-w5100-ethernet-shield)  , but it is so general. and also what ı should use replace for "arping" in windows.

**3-Arduino Clon Problem.**

next week we try it with with original arduino ,

I will inform everybody.

SO, any suggestion,tool, or some diagnostic tool for the problem I'm open all the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Our Problem is a specific switch model!

Here is the model: https://www.zyxel.com/tr/tr/products_services/es_108a.shtml?t=p   (zyxel ES-108E)

When we directly connect arduino to zyxel switch, and ping arduino from another device in the network only some of pings successful.(Roughly %15 succeeded).

But if we use another switch model or don't directly connect to zyxel switch, it works fine.

I dont know why it is not working with zyxel but problem is the switch!